# migration multi tenant .net 5 to 7

Tags: asp.net-core, multi-tenant

I want to update multi tenant from 5 to 7

Example

```
city-a.site.com
city-b.site.com
```

Context

```
public class MemoryDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MemoryDbContext(DbContextOptions<MemoryDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected MemoryDbContext()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
}
```

class TenantAttribute

```
public class TenantAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly MemoryDbContext _memoryDbContext;

    public TenantAttribute(MemoryDbContext memoryDbContext)
    {
        _memoryDbContext = memoryDbContext;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionExecutingContext)
    {
        var fullAddress = actionExecutingContext.HttpContext?.Request?
            .Headers?["Host"].ToString()?.Split('.');

        if (fullAddress.Length < 2)
        {
            //Redirect WWW
            var redirectUrl = "https://www.example.com";
            actionExecutingContext.Result = new RedirectResult(redirectUrl, true);
        }
        else
        {
            var subdomain = fullAddress[0];
            var tenant = _memoryDbContext.Tenants
                .SingleOrDefault(t => string.Equals(t.Host, subdomain, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            if (tenant != null)
            {
                actionExecutingContext.RouteData.Values.Add("tenant", tenant);
                base.OnActionExecuting(actionExecutingContext);
            }
            else
            {
                //Redirect WWW
                var redirectUrl = "https://www.example.com";
                actionExecutingContext.Result = new RedirectResult(redirectUrl, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class Tenant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Host { get; set; }
    //City Or Group
    public int Cog { get; set; }
    public int MainId { get; set; }
    public string SubId { get; set; }
}
```

CustomServices

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(TenantAttribute));
```

ConfigureServices

```
services.AddDbContext<MemoryDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("MemoryDb"));
```

Worked in .net 5

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var context = services.GetRequiredService<MemoryDbContext>();
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        if (!context.Tenants.Any())
        {
            context.Tenants.Add(new Tenant() { Name = "City1", Host = "city-a", Cog = 2, MainId = 1, SubId = "1" });
            context.Tenants.Add(new Tenant() { Name = "City2", Host = "city-b", Cog = 2, MainId = 2, SubId = "2" });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    host.Run();
}
```

I tried this in .NET 7:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
ConfigureLogging(builder.Logging, builder.Environment, builder.Configuration);
ConfigureServices(builder.Services, builder.Configuration, builder.Environment);

var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).Build();

using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
{
    scope.RunScopedServicec<MemoryDbContext>();
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var context = services.GetRequiredService<MemoryDbContext>();

    context.Database.EnsureCreated();

    if (!context.Tenants.Any())
    {
        context.Tenants.Add(new Tenant() { Name = "City1", Host = "city-a", Cog = 2, MainId = 1, SubId = "1" });
            context.Tenants.Add(new Tenant() { Name = "City2", Host = "city-b", Cog = 2, MainId = 2, SubId = "2" });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

host.Run();

var webApp = builder.Build();
```

Error

> System.InvalidOperationException
> HResult=0x80131509
> Message=No service for type 'Site.DataLayer.Context.MemoryDbContext' has been registered.
>
> Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions
>
> StackTrace:
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
> at Program.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
ConfigureLogging(builder.Logging, builder.Environment, builder.Configuration);
ConfigureServices(builder.Services, builder.Configuration, builder.Environment);

var webApp = builder.Build();

using (var scope = webApp.Services.CreateScope())
{
    scope.RunScopedServicec<MemoryDbContext>();
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var context = services.GetRequiredService<MemoryDbContext>();

    context.Database.EnsureCreated();

    if (!context.Tenants.Any())
    {
        context.Tenants.Add(new Tenant() { Name = "City1", Host = "city-a", Cog = 2, MainId = 1, SubId = "1" });
            context.Tenants.Add(new Tenant() { Name = "City2", Host = "city-b", Cog = 2, MainId = 2, SubId = "2" });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

webApp.Run();
```